# Why don't virtual devices on android studio start up

Tags: android-studio, sdk, dji-sdk

I want to use the DJI SDK Mobile SDK to fly a drone.
SO,I use the DJI Developer site (https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/application-development-workflow/workflow-integrate.html)to integrate android studio projects.
However, even if the program is entered according to the site, "Hello, world" is not displayed on the virtual device.
Specifically, "import SDK Demo keep stopping." is displayed after the app starts for a moment on the virtual device.
Please help me !!!

Android Studios version : 3.5
Mobile SDKs version :4.2

I tried Android Studio with some version(ex.3.0/3.5).But, everytime "Hello, world" is not displayed on the virtual device.

Answer (score 0):

Without having more details about what you've done, it is hard to say what your problem is.

HOWEVER, the SDKs require an "Application Key" to be generated via your DJI account, whereby you access a special web page that allows you to give a name to the App you propose to create, as well as a bundle identifier like : com.yourCompany.yourNewApp.  After providing such basic "App" info's that DJI webpage will generate a long hexadecimal number which is your App Key.   So again, without that App Key (number) being added (edited into) to your App, you will not be going anywhere.   DJI uses this App Key for keeping track of all developer's Apps, and where those Apps are running.

Specifically,  the DJI SDK gives an immediate error as soon as the SDK initialization is attempted, when/where attempted without a valid App Key.

So again, without more details from your problem, it is hard to say that the problem/solution (stated here) applies to you.   But this certainly is a very common "newbie" or "getting started" problem.

Comment: Per the problem/solution given above, one might be tempted to think that the DJI "sample" apps should already be ready to go, with a pre-installed "App Key".   HOWEVER, that would be a wrong assumption.   DJI wants to track ALL developed Apps that use their SDK, even their own demo/example apps.   If they provided their own sample apps ready to go with a pre-installed key, then they would have no way of knowing which of their registered developers is actually running that App.

Comment: Thank you for answering!
The App key in the answer has already been entered in "Please enter your App key".
Regarding errors, when I entered sample code like the homepage, there were a lot of errors, but it disappeared when I followed the display of "Alt + Enter", so there is no error so far.
I would like to know if there is a way to post the program to you.